# Why Yii2 is down with try/catch?

Tags: php, yii2

I insert an entry in which there is a duplicate of the primary key.

```
public function actionInc()
{
        $add = new Country();
        $add->code = 'QI';
        $add->name = 'Qiang';
        $add->population = '4444444';
    try {
        $add->save();
        return $this->render('inc', [
            'count' => 'Ok',
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return $this->render('inc', [
            'count' => 'Error',
        ]);
    }
}
```

But I need that the application does not down, and continued to work, but it does not work...
[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you tried to  `catch (\yii\db\Exception $exception)`?

Comment: @csminb It works. Make your comment a response please so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check which Exception subclass you are importing in your use statements
yii throws `\yii\db\Exception` for db-related errors.
all of yii's exceptions inherit from [\Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php)

```
// db related exceptions
catch (\yii\db\Exception $exception) 

// any exception throwin by yii
catch (\yii\base\Exception $exception)

// any php exception
catch (\Exception $exception)
```

Comment: I am using `\yii\db\Exception`. and I my code I am doing try catch `try
                       { }
                       catch (Exception $ex)
                       {
                           var_dump($ex->getMessage());
                           die();
                       }`

Comment: But still the block is not working, and I am getting this error `exception exception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement` on mouseover `Exception`

Comment: i'm nost sure what your issue is. was this an inspection error in your ide?